# Docker app fails to launch with shinyproxy in docker-compose, works with run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, shinyproxy

I have a shinyproxy app that works fine with `docker run ...`

```
docker run --name=shinyproxy -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --net telethonkids-net -p 80:8080 --rm telethonkids/shinyproxy
```

by when I try the following docker-compose shinyproxy loads on the browser, but the app times out when trying to start (Container unresponsive):

```
version: "3.6"
services:
    shinyproxy:
      build:
        context: ./shinyproxy
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      networks:
        - telethonkids-net
      volumes:
        - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      ports:
        - 80:8080

networks:
  telethonkids-net:
```

I'm running this on a Ubuntu 18.04 virtual box. There are a few other questions with similar titles, but none that I saw that matched my problem.

Here's my application.yaml

```
proxy:
  title: Shiny Proxy Landing Page
  hide-navbar: true
  landing-page: /
  port: 8080
  docker:
    internal-networking: true
  specs:
  - id: id1
    display-name: xxx
    description: yyy
    container-cmd: ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
    container-image: telethonkids/zzz
    container-env:
      user: 'shiny'
      environment:
        - APPLICATION_LOGS_TO_STDOUT=false
```

Shinyproxy Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

RUN mkdir -p /opt/shinyproxy/
RUN wget https://www.shinyproxy.io/downloads/shinyproxy-2.1.0.jar -O /opt/shinyproxy/shinyproxy.jar
COPY application.yml /opt/shinyproxy/application.yml

WORKDIR /opt/shinyproxy/
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/shinyproxy/shinyproxy.jar"]
```

Comment: Do you really need the volume to be mounted? `/var/run/docker.sock`. Could you remove it and run your app for once?

Comment: Removing the volume brings up another error "UT005023: Exception handling request to app/zzz" - this also comes up when removing it from docker run

Comment: What's in that `Dockerfile`?  Does running the same `image:` in the `docker-compose.yml`, instead of a custom `build:`, work consistently?

Comment: I've added the `Dockefile` to the question. I also tried building it and running `image` in the `docker-compose.yml`, but to no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this one comes down to a rookie error. I had created a network to run my app via. `docker run --net telethonkids-net`. This was causing issues when trying to use the same network inside `docker-compose` with:

networks:
  telethonkids-net:

After reading the documentation a bit more closely, I could use this pre-created network with the following:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: telethonkids-net
```

and adding

```
  networks:
    default:
```

to the shinyproxy service.

And the app started. The fix was to just remove the created network in docker and create it in `docker-compose`. I also needed to name the network so it conformed to what I had in `shinyproxy/application.yml`.

```
networks:
  telethonkids-net:
    name: telethonkids-net
```

Answer (score 1):

Since docker-compose v3.5, you can just create the network from inside the `docker-compose.yml` instead of having to create it before running `docker-compose up`

As an example:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  shinyproxy:
    image: myimage
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: "ShinyProxy"
    networks:
      shinyproxy-net:

networks:
  shinyproxy-net:
    name: shinyproxy-net
```

So now a simply `docker-compose up` creates the network

Reference: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3736#issuecomment-365318122